# Facebook OmniAuth Devise

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, devise, omniauth

Im using rails 3 with devise and omniauth-facebook, I click on the "Login with facebook link", it redirects me to facebook page of my app, I login with my facebook credentials, it redirects me back to my Rails app successfully, and it also added my facebook email to the users table, but how do I access the logged in users details?

I tried using the devise user model, but no luck

here is what i have

```
<%= link_to "Sign in with Facebook", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook) %>

<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <div>Signed in as... <%= current_user.email %></div>
<% else %>
    not signed in
<% end %>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks guys! :D

Answer (score 2):

I think here you can find what you're looking for, read and watch the article carefully :)
http://railscasts.com/episodes/236-omniauth-part-2

Answer (score 0):

You may also find the [Koala Facebook gem](https://github.com/arsduo/koala/) handy.